# jQuery modify contains statement to filter

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I currently have a small problem with jQuery with a contains statement. It is catching all possible matches when I want the exact match. I realized that a filter statement would probably be one of the best repalcements to get an exact match.

However, I have looked through multiple examples and still can't quite get this statement to work.

Here is the original statement with the contains in it.

```
function showDropDown(){
    $(".sf-with-ul):contains('"+stringToMatch+"')").parent().showSuperfishUl();
};
```

This statement is supposed to show a dropdown menu and will show multiple menus. If one menu has "This" and another has "This1" and I says contains "This" I get both. I want to create a statement with filter in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extra `)` in the selector. Try this:

```
function showDropDown(){
    $(".sf-with-ul:contains('"+stringToMatch+"')").parent().showSuperfishUl();
};
```

or:

```
$(".sf-with-ul").filter(function(){
       return $(this).text() == stringToMatch
}).parent().showSuperfishUl();
```

Comment: That extra ) was a typo on my part. I'm not looking to keep this contains statement. I want to create a statement that will use the filter selector instead so I can get an exact match but I am having a hard time with the filter selector.